# How can I typeset non-square matrices?

Tags: matrices

I'd like to typeset a non-square matrix in the manner of `$\begin{array}$`, but I don't know how. How can I typeset a 4 x 3 matrix, for example?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you know `array` I  don't understand the problem. Just specify three columns, and add four rows ...

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing this but got a "! Paragraph ended before \partialderivative  was complete." error when I tried to compile (it's a matrix of partial derivatives).

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: So I tried 'array' with just simple letters for entries and it worked, so the error must be elsewhere. I'll make this a separate question I guess. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load `amsmath` and type, say:

```
\[\begin{bmatrix}
   a&b&c\\
   d&e&f\\
   g&h&i\\
   k&l&m
  \end{bmatrix}\]
```

if you want a bracketed matrix, `pmatrix` for a matrix with parentheses, `vmatrix` for a determinant or `Vmatrix` for a matrix with double rules.

Loading `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case), you may use the `\b-p-v-Vmatrix*` environments, which allows you to specify the alignment of columns: `[r], [l]` or `[c]` (default).